# Using Selenium to Input Cypher Commands into Neo4j

Tags: python, selenium, neo4j

So I am trying to automate query input into Neo4j browser. Since the area where the text is written into is not an input field, rather in `<span>` tags as below:
[image]

I would add in the the cypher command `MATCH (n) RETURN n LIMIT 10` through python like this:

```
driver.execute_script('return document.getElementsByClassName("view-line")[0].outerHTML=\'<div style="top:0px;height:23px;" class="view-line"><span><span class="mtk4">MATCH</span><span class="mtk15">&nbsp;</span><span class="mtk3">(</span><span class="mtk15">n</span><span class="mtk3">)</span><span class="mtk15">&nbsp;</span><span class="mtk4">RETURN</span><span class="mtk15">&nbsp;n&nbsp;</span><span class="mtk4">LIMIT</span><span class="mtk15">&nbsp;</span><span class="mtk13">10</span></span></div>\'')
```

After I edit the outer HTML using python and click the run button, the text would just disappear. I cannot figure out what could be wrong with this. I'm new to using selenium as well. So not sure if it is something that I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

the question is very unclear!But I realized that you need to enter something in span
try use

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#your selector'))).send_keys('')
```